# Работа с двумя базами, перед запуском приложения

Tags: firebird

Доброе время суток форумчане,
Такая ситуация:
Есть приложение (*Delphi 10.2*) работающее с базой (на *firebird3*), в которой есть таблица («*user_data*») пользователей с паролями.
Есть библиотека которая управляет доступом входа в приложение, т.е. перед запуском приложения, запускается библиотека, которая читает из реестра путь к базе, потом вынимает пароль из таблицы («*user_data*») и 2 варианта или запускает приложение (пароль правильный) или выдает сообщение что пароль неправильный.

Возникла ситуация создать вторую БД (в той же директории, что и первая), **с теми же пользователями**, что и в первой БД. Сразу же захотелось использовать одну таблицу на 2 БД.
Само приложение умеет работать с двумя БД (просто несколько *TIBDataBase*). А вот библиотека не умеет, работать с несколькими БД.
Может в *FB3* уже появилась возможность делать *VIEW* в одной БД из другой БД. Читал мануал по *FB3* – не нашел. Хотел сделать *VIEW* «*user_data*» из первой БД для второй БД.

Или может есть другой вариант?
Просто не хотелось переделывать библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Firebird можно получить данные из другой БД как минимум при помощи конструкции

```
EXECUTE STATEMENT …
ON EXTERNAL …
```

Подробности по ссылке: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-on-external

**UPD**

Сам вызов EXECUTE STATEMENT лучше всего поместить в хранимую процедуру.

Если есть возможность написать запрос так, чтобы данные фильтровались в удаленной БД, и возвращалась одна строка, то сразу помещаем результат в переменные

```
EXECUTE STATEMENT …
ON EXTERNAL …
INTO список переменных
```

Иначе делаем курсор FOR

```
FOR
  EXECUTE STATEMENT …
  ON EXTERNAL …
  INTO список переменных
DO
…
```

В использовании именно VIEW не вижу смысла, т.к. с процедурой тоже можно выполнять JOIN. А можно обернуть в представление.

Comment: Подскажите, а куда эту конструкцию подставить в *хранимую процедуру* или в *view*? чтобы я мог получить доступ к данным таблицы из другой БД перед запуском приложения. Хотя в описании к конструкции написано, что ее можно использовать в PSQL-блоках, триггерах и процедурах. Тогда если в процедуре, как можно запустить процедуру и откуда ее запускать?

Comment: А понял, наверное  "EXECUTE STATEMENT … ON EXTERNAL" в хранимую процедуру, + создание view с вызовом этой процедуры. Правильно?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: В принципе, я так и сделал... **Спасибо за ответ**